# Need help with circuit task

Tags: circuit-design

I just began digital technology in my school and im struggling with one task my teacher gave me. Since I have holidays right now I cant ask my teacher (living in Germany). So I hope I'm at the right spot here!

---

This is the task he gave me:

> 1. Create a circuit (functional block diagram) which only has a permanent output signal **K2** if the input **S1** was temporary activated. If the input **S1** is temporary activated again the ouput **K2** should go off.
>      ***Please note:*** The output **K2** should not flicker if **S1** is permanently activated.

I also have to create a functional equation. Dont know if mine is actually correct:
[image]

*Thanks for any help!*

Comment: What does "FBD" mean?

Comment: @Andyaka functional block diagram

Comment: What you want can be achieved by what is termed a [**toggling latch**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1021&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=toggling+electronic+latch&oq=toggling+electronic+latch&gs_l=img.3...5194.8656.0.9120.11.11.0.0.0.0.303.1999.2-8j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.0.0.1GQvTe1rcG8)  or [**toggling flipflop.**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1021&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=toggling+flipflop.+&oq=toggling+flipflop.+&gs_l=img.3...52293.52293.0.53411.1.1.0.0.0.0.245.245.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.qpj1afRfwP4)

Comment: @flosommerfeld Welcome to EE.SE. you should rephrase the title of your question to be more specific. You will get more attention by the community and, consequently, more answers.

Comment: @Andyaka Functional Block Diagram?

Comment: Your equation is useless and wrong because it asserts a static truth connecting some *mathematical* variables, whereas the circuit is dynamic: it has a time-dependent behavior involving some *state* variables and their transitions (more like variables in an imperative programming language). Note that "S1 XOR (NOT S1)" is a tautology; the expression is true for all possible values of S1. But we know that K2 is not always true!

Comment: @Kaz Thanks, im going to write that good clarification into my IT-folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by what is termed a [**toggling latch**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1021&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=toggling+electronic+latch&oq=toggling+electronic+latch&gs_l=img.3...5194.8656.0.9120.11.11.0.0.0.0.303.1999.2-8j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.0.0.1GQvTe1rcG8)  or [**toggling flipflop.**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1021&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=toggling+flipflop.+&oq=toggling+flipflop.+&gs_l=img.3...52293.52293.0.53411.1.1.0.0.0.0.245.245.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.qpj1afRfwP4)

These are electronic devices which input a "clock" signal and change state once per clock cycle. They often have two outputs which can be considred to be
"high" or "low" or
1 or 0 or
true or false.

So a two output flipflop has outputs either in state 0/1 or 1/0.
Clock signals may be designed to trigger the change of state on the rising edge or the falling edge or in some cases the clock level (0 or 1) latches or unlatches the latch. This is important when a data line is also involved - a complication bot relevant in this case.

You can compare the above description to your requirement and the many circuits referenced above and should be able to use this information to design a simple low cost solution.

---

**Here are some typical examples**

I am not suggesting that any of these is the best solution or even a suitable one in your case - but they show what is typically involved.

1. uses two transistors and quite a few other parts. It has set and clear and toggle inputs, making it quite versatile.
2. Uses a "D flipflop"  to make a very simple toggle. If you end up using something like this you **absolutely must** do enough research to understand how and why it works. Just serving up yur prof the fbd will get you in deep trouble if you cannot explaimn it.
3. Is similar to 1. but with a somewhat subtle and major difference in operation. Understanding how 1 & 3 works will greatly advance your analog electronics understanding.
4. Uses a JK flipflop. It looks like 2. and is BUT there are also major differences. If you end up being able to explain D & JK flipflops and how to toggle them and the differences you will have done well. If not DO NOT submit them to your prof or else!

[image] ##

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! It works in my simulator now.

Comment: @flosommerfeld You MUST understand why !!!! MUSt. DO NOT just simulate it. Look up D flip flop and JK and their truth tables / state tables and UNDERSTAND what happens. Or else !